# javascript exceed timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I use jquery to develop mobile application, here is my code below the problem that when I add 5 or 6 line to the page contained all goes well. but if I add multiple line displays error message: Javascript execution exeeded timeout.

```
function succes_recu_list_rubrique(tx, results)   //apÃ©s avoire remplir sqlite
{
    console.log('ENTRééééééééééééééé---')

    $('#lbtn').prepend("<legend>Selectionner un Rubrique</legend><br>");
    for( var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++  )            //Remplir tableau liste des identifiants Ã©tapes
    { 
    $('#lbtn').append("<input name='opt1' checked type='radio' value="+results.rows.item(i).IdRubrique+"    id="+results.rows.item(i).IdRubrique+" />");
    $('#lbtn').append('<label for='+results.rows.item(i).IdRubrique+'>'+results.rows.item(i).LibelleRubrique+'</label>');   
    }
    $('#lbtn').append('<a href="#page_dialog2"     class="offer2"      data-rel="dialog"    data-role="button" >Consulter</a>').trigger('create');
    $('#lbtn').append('<a href="#'+id_grp_rub+'"   data-role="button"             data-rel="back" data-theme="c" >Cancel</a> ').trigger('create');

}
```

Comment: Could you provide more information as to what are the "lines" you are adding ? where ?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know, how big is the results.row ?
But you should start caching your jQuery objects and try to minimize your DOM-insertions

The followings is untested but it will point you in the right direction:

```
function succes_recu_list_rubrique(tx, results)   //apÃ©s avoire remplir sqlite
{
    console.log('ENTRééééééééééééééé---')

    var htmlToAppend = "";
    var $lbtn = $('#lbtn');

    htmlToAppend += "<legend>Selectionner un Rubrique</legend><br>";

    for( var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++  )            //Remplir tableau liste des identifiants Ã©tapes
    { 
        htmlToAppend += "<input name='opt1' checked type='radio' value="+results.rows.item(i).IdRubrique+" id="+results.rows.item(i).IdRubrique+" />";
        htmlToAppend += "<label for='+results.rows.item(i).IdRubrique+'>'+results.rows.item(i).LibelleRubrique+'</label>";
    }
    $lbtn.append(htmlToAppend);

    $lbtn.append('<a href="#page_dialog2"     class="offer2"      data-rel="dialog"    data-role="button" >Consulter</a>').trigger('create');
    $lbtn.append('<a href="#'+id_grp_rub+'"   data-role="button"             data-rel="back" data-theme="c" >Cancel</a> ').trigger('create');

}
```

Comment: @user1866265 any response to this ?

Comment: well a gave you an answer, have you tried it/does it work ?
How many entries does results.row contain ?

Comment: yes i tried with your answer but same error. results.row contain = 150

Answer (score 0):

@soderslatt is headed in the right directions. See http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly for how to append to an element that is NOT attached to the DOM (and avoid repaint & reflow) and then append it to the DOM and pay the penalty only once

Answer (score 0):

The below solution will solve your issue. The trick is to use the setTimeout function with a very small number of 1 millisecond to wait before executing the code. Using the mentioned way will allow you to unlock the thread and avoid the exceed timeout error.

Sample Example:

```
function succes_recu_list_rubrique(tx, results) {

    var i = 0;

    function appendOperation() {
        $('#lbtn').append(
            [
                "<input name='opt1' checked type='radio' value=", results.rows.item(i).IdRubrique, " id=", results.rows.item(i).IdRubrique, " />",
                "<label for=", results.rows.item(i).IdRubrique, ">", results.rows.item(i).LibelleRubrique, "</label>"
            ].join("")
        );

        if (i++ < results.rows.length) {
            setTimeout(appendOperation, 1);
        } 
    }
    appendOperation();
}
```