# How can I change the code so that it can execute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery to develop mobile applications. The problem is that when I add 5 or 6 lines to the page, all goes well, but if I add say 120 lines it displays an error message: `Javascript execution exceeded timeout`.

```
function succes_recu_list_rubrique(tx, results) { //après avoir rempli sqlite
  console.log('ENTRééééééééééééééé---');
  $('#lbtn').prepend("<legend>Sélectionner une rubrique</legend><br>");
  for(var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) {
    //Remplir tableau liste des identifiants étapes
    $('#lbtn').append("<input name='opt1' checked type='radio' value="+results.rows.item(i).IdRubrique+" id="+results.rows.item(i).IdRubrique+" />");
    $('#lbtn').append('<label for='+results.rows.item(i).IdRubrique+'>'+results.rows.item(i).LibelleRubrique+'</label>');   
  }
  $('#lbtn').append('<a href="#page_dialog2" class="offer2" data-rel="dialog" data-role="button" >Consulter</a>').trigger('create');
  $('#lbtn').append('<a href="#'+id_grp_rub+'" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>').trigger('create');
}
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658105/javascript-exceed-timeout/13658764#13658764

Comment: yes duplicate because no one have an idea and give me good response

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `.append` four separate times, you can call it one time with all of the html in one string and call one trigger on both of the newly created anchors.

Comment: for( var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++  )            //Remplir tableau liste des identifiants Ã©tapes
   { 
  temp +="<input name='opt1' checked type='radio' value="+results.rows.item(i).IdRubrique+"    id="+results.rows.item(i).IdRubrique+" />";
  temp +='<label for='+results.rows.item(i).IdRubrique+'>'+results.rows.item(i).LibelleRubrique+'</label>';   
 }
 $('#lbtn').append(temp).trigger('create');

Same Error: Time Out

Answer (score 0):

Create a local variable for your selection:

```
var temp = $('#lbtn')
```

add all your lines to that variable

```
temp += "code here";
```

etc.

and then append to the element once.

Comment: for( var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++  )            //Remplir tableau liste des identifiants Ã©tapes
   { 
  temp +="<input name='opt1' checked type='radio' value="+results.rows.item(i).IdRubrique+"    id="+results.rows.item(i).IdRubrique+" />";
  temp +='<label    for='+results.rows.item(i).IdRubrique+'>'+results.rows.item(i).LibelleRubrique+'</label>';   
 }
 $('#lbtn').append(temp).trigger('create');

Same Error: javascript Timeout Exceed